# Дешифровка алгоритмом Рабина

Tags: c#, шифрование, криптография

Работал над криптосистемой Рабина, шифровка далась без проблем, однако при дешифровке возникают проблемы. Вразумительных алгоритмнов и формул в интернетах практически нет, а те что есть работают через раз а именно: алгоритм корректо работает при p и q равных 11 и 19, 19 и 23. При остальныных ни один из 4х возвращаемых варианта не соответствует исходному файлу. Хотелось бы узнать писал ли кто-нибудь Рабина для произвольных файлов или хотя бы какие формулы для дешифровки рабочие. Кусочки кода дешифровки на шарпах прилагаются.

```
    private byte[] DecryptOneByte(uint c, int p, int q)
{
    int n = p * q;

    int[] m = CalculateM(p, q, c);  // [0] для p, [1] для q

    int[] y = AddFuctions.ExtendedEuclidian(p, q);  // [0] для p, [1] для q
    y[1] = p + y[1];

    int[] result = new int[4];
    result[0] = ((m[0] * q * y[1] + m[1] * p * y[0]) % n);
    result[1] = (-result[0] + n) % n;
    result[2] = ((m[0] * q * y[1] - m[1] * p * y[0]) % n);
    result[3] = (-result[2] + n) % n;

    for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
    {
        result[i] = Convert(result[i], n);
    }

    return new byte[4] { (byte)result[0], (byte)result[1], (byte)result[2], (byte)result[3] };

}

    private int Convert(int r, int n)
    {
        if (r < 0)
        {
            return n + r;
        }
        else
        {
            return r;
        }
    }

    private int[] CalculateM(int p, int q, uint c)
    {
        int[] m = new int[2];

        m[0] = (int)(Math.Pow((int)c, ((p + 1) / 4)) % p);
        m[1] = (int)(Math.Pow((int)c, ((q + 1) / 4)) % q);

        return m;
    }
}

    public static int[] ExtendedEuclidian(int p, int q)
    {
        int[] y = new int[2] { 0, 0 };

        gcd(p, q, ref y[0], ref y[1]);

        return y;
    }

    private static int gcd(int a, int b, ref int y0, ref int y1)
    {
        if (a == 0)
        {
            y0 = 0;
            y1 = 1;

            return b;
        }

        int x0 = 0;
        int x1 = 0;

        int d = gcd(b % a, a, ref x0, ref x1);

        y0 = x1 - (b / a) * x0;
        y1 = x0;

        return d;
    }
```

Comment: Категорически не стоит использовать криптографию, о которой в интернетах ничего нет.